# Using a dynamic database connection in a Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

My application has multiple clients, each client with its own database. The application for the clients is plugin-based, so the tables for each client have the same structure. But client A doesn't necessarily have the same tables as client B (because client B uses more/other plugins).

I've created a "client"-connection within my `database.php` config file:

```
    'client' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_CLIENT_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_CLIENT_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_CLIENT_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_CLIENT_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_CLIENT_PASSWORD', ''),
        // and so on
    ],
```

In my migration file I loop through all clients a want to rerun each migration one time per client:

```
public function up()
{
    foreach (\App\Models\Clients\Client::all() as $client){

        if($client->hasCompleteDatabaseConnectionDetails()){

            $client->establishDatabaseConnection();

            Schema::connection('client')->create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('meta_title')->nullable();
                $table->string('meta_description')->nullable();
                $table->string('title')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my relevant methods within my Client-Model:

```
public function hasCompleteDatabaseConnectionDetails(): bool
{
    return !is_null($this->db_host)
        && !is_null($this->db_port)
        && !is_null($this->db_user)
        && !is_null($this->db_name)
        && !is_null($this->db_password);
}

public function couldConnectToDatabase(): bool
{
    try {
        DB::connection('client')->statement('SELECT TRUE');
        config(['client.can_connect_to_database' => true]);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        config(['client.can_connect_to_database' => false]);
    }
    return config('client.can_connect_to_database');
}

protected function setDatabaseConnectionInConfig(): void
{
    config(['database.connections.client.host' => $this->db_host]);
    config(['database.connections.client.port' => $this->db_port]);
    config(['database.connections.client.database' => $this->db_name]);
    config(['database.connections.client.username' => $this->db_user]);
    config(['database.connections.client.password' => $this->db_password]);
}

public function establishDatabaseConnection(): void
{
    if ($this->hasCompleteDatabaseConnectionDetails()) {
        config(['client.has_qualified_database_credentials' => true]);
        $this->setDatabaseConnectionInConfig();
        if($this->couldConnectToDatabase()){
            config(['client.can_connect_to_database' => true]);
        } else {
            config(['client.can_connect_to_database' => false]);
        }
    } else {
        config(['client.has_qualified_database_credentials' => false]);
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` I get an error saying that could not connect using user ""@"localhost". So somehow the application doesn't save the credentials. How can I fix this? 
I don't want to add a new connection in`database.php` for each new client because new clients should be addable from a web interface, so the current connection must be setable dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection has already been cached by Laravel, so any changes to the database config won't have any effect until you run `DB::purge($connection)`.

```
public function couldConnectToDatabase(): bool
{
    try {
        DB::purge('client');
        DB::connection('client')->statement('SELECT TRUE');
        config(['client.can_connect_to_database' => true]);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        config(['client.can_connect_to_database' => false]);
    }
    return config('client.can_connect_to_database');
}
```

You can view `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php` for more clues/information about how the connections works.